# auto-escape to prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, html, templates, escaping, xss

(when rendering a HTML template)

```
<hidden name=”param${ns?htmlattr}” />
<a href=”${url?urlencode}”>${usercontent?htmlencode}</a>
${rawhtml?htmlliteral}
<script>
var a = “${str?jsstr}”; //null becomes “”
var b = ${str?quote,jsstr}; //allow null, render quotes if nonnull
var c = ${func?jsliteral}
var ${func?jsidentifier} = null;
</script>
```

- jsstr escapes `\t\b\f\n\r\\\'\"` and `</`
- jsliteral escapes `</`
- jsidentifier replaces non-alnum with a dummy character
- xmlattr escapes `<>&` and filters characters that aren't legal UTF-8
- htmlencode encodes almost all edge cases into stuff like `&amp;`
- quote causes a string to render out quoted (including empty), or `null`

A few of these might not be relevant for security--they just help the code stay sane. Which escape mode do we choose as the default to help prevent XSS -- be "more secure" by default? What if we default to the most restrictive (htmlencode) and relax/switch excape modes from there?

I'm not interested in discussing the merits of all these escape modes -- for better or worse, they all exist in our codebase. Am I missing any modes? Any good reading material?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://js-quasis-libraries-and-repl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/safetemplate.html

That defines contexts in HTML and a mapping from those contexts to escaping functions.

For a runnable example, take a look at http://js-quasis-libraries-and-repl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html .  Try starting with the "Safe HTML" examples from the dropdown menu at the top-right.

To address your specific example, `jsliteral` looks a little widgy.  What benefit do you get from html encoding anything inside a `<script>` block?  The content is CDATA.

What are `jsidentifier` and `jsliteral` guarding?  Do they stop dangerous identifiers like `eval` from being assigned?  They should probably prevent `<!--` in addition to `</` since an injected `/*<!--` could cause the `</script>` to be ignored possibly allowing an later interpolation to masquerade as script content.